# How can I decode a low-level return data from a reverting call?

Tags: solidity, revert, returndata

Take the following low-level call written in Solidity:

```
(bool success, bytes memory response) =
          address(proxy).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(plugins.reverter.withReasonString.selector));
```

I know that this call will revert because I wrote the `plugins.reverter` contract (this is a test):

```
contract TargetReverter {
    function withReasonString() external pure {
        revert("You shall not pass");
    }
}
```

I want to ABI decode the `response` into a string, but I cannot make it work. The following code does not work:

```
abi.decode(response, (string));
```

I imagine that this is because `response` starts with a 4-byte function selector:

```
0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012596f75207368616c6c206e6f7420706173730000000000000000000000000000
```

How can I turn the bytes above into a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found another solution that is much more gas efficient, as it uses a native Error function to parse the response:

```
{
    (bool success, bytes memory response) = address(proxy).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(plugins.reverter.withReasonString.selector));

    /// Signature for "Error(string)"
    bytes4 errorSignature = 0x08c379a0;

    /// Make sure the response is from a standard revert()
    if (!success && bytes4(response) == errorSignature) {
        (bool success2, bytes memory response2) = address(this).call(response);

        string errorText = abi.decode(response2, (string));

        return errorText;
    }
}
```

And following this we define the function that can parse the revert() encoded data

```
function Error(string memory text) public pure returns(string memory) {
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

abi.decode() needs to receive ABI-encoded data without signatures, but revert() returns a standard Error(string), resulting in ABI-encoded signature+data.

So, you just need to remove the signature before decoding:

```
if (!success) {
    for (uint256 i; i < response.length-4;) {
        response[i] = response[i+4];
        unchecked{ ++i; }
    }
    
    string memory errorMessage = abi.decode(response, (string));

    return errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: Interesting to note that abi.decodeWithSelector() was proposed time ago, but has not yet been implemented: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3876